# Pandas update row value based on group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have such df

```
product  type  price 
  A       1      10
  A       2      15
  A       3      NAN
  A       4      20
  B       1      40
  B       2      30
  B       3      NAN
  B       4      5
  C       1      80
  C       2      70 
  C       3      90
  C       4      NAN 
  D       6      75
  D       8      40
```

I want to update the value of price (Not necessarily NAN) based on another value

```
If (type == 3):
   price == df['type' == 1]
elif ( type == 4): 
   price == df['type' == 2]
elif ( type == 8):
   price == df['type' == 6]
```

Something like this the condition. I tried for each using the following:
`df.loc[df['type'] == 3, 'price'] = df[df['type']==1]['price'].iloc[0]`

The following way works just that the value `10` is replaced at both product `A, B and C`.
Is there a way that this value can be updated according to the product group. The expected outcome as following :

```
product  type  price 
  A       1      10
  A       2      15
  A       3      10
  A       4      15
  B       1      40
  B       2      30
  B       3      40
  B       4      30
  C       1      80
  C       2      70 
  C       3      80
  C       4      70
  D       6      75
  D       8      75
```

Note: using `transform('first')` may not be appropriate in this use case. Not necessarily each product will have all the type (1-10)
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **Not necessarily NAN**? why doesn't the values in row `4` get updated?

Comment: Because below here the solution is to use ```fillna``` but what I'm trying to do is update/replace the value of price based on the condition like I've stated. The ```type``` may/may not have a ```price```. That is meant by Not necessarily NAN

Comment: That's what I'm asking: Shouldn't you change your **expected output** to really reflect what you **expect**?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing out, initially the question was for NAN then once edited I forgot to edit the expected outcome. My bad. Now I've updated the expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,you need to fillna with the first value of each group:

```
df['price']=df['price'].fillna(df.groupby('product')['price'].transform('first'))
print(df)
```

---

```
   product  type  price
0       A     1   10.0
1       A     2   15.0
2       A     3   10.0
3       A     4   20.0
4       B     1   40.0
5       B     2   30.0
6       B     3   40.0
7       B     4    5.0
```

EDIT , bases on edited question , you can try pivotting and filling na with the respective columns:

```
piv = df.set_index(['product','type'])['price'].unstack()
piv = piv.fillna({3:piv[1],4:piv[2]})
out = piv.stack().reset_index(name='price')
```

---

```
print(out)

   product  type  price
0        A     1   10.0
1        A     2   15.0
2        A     3   10.0
3        A     4   20.0
4        B     1   40.0
5        B     2   30.0
6        B     3   40.0
7        B     4    5.0
8        C     1   80.0
9        C     2   70.0
10       C     3   90.0
11       C     4   70.0
```

Comment: Oh sorry that I didn't mention above. The df that i showed was just a template structure. Basically the type list is long. around 30~ . Therefore at certain point i need to get the value from another point. Let say in this example, type 3 get from type 1. But reality a lot more, (type 5 get type 2, type 9 get type 6, etc etc.) That's why I'll prefer the method we can express the type and get the iloc value

Comment: @MohamedAfiq we would need an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, updated the question. Would be glad if you could take a look at it again. I missed out the main information which is the conditions.

Comment: @MohamedAfiq Can you please check now?

Comment: Yes it works, I've also trying on unstacking just now, then I realized that some of my data which could not be affected by ```fillna``` I'm extremely sorry as I overlooked this. For certain situation the type may contain data, but those data are either wrong/is used for reference for other type. Some ```type``` may have the price, but the price must be updated/replace. I was trying using ```np.where``` it didnt work still. I've edited a little on the question to elaborate this. Sorry !

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
for x,y in zip([3,4,8],[1,2,6]):
    df.loc[df['type'].eq(x), 'price'] = df.loc[df['type'].eq(y),'price'].values
```

Output:

```
   product  type price
0        A     1    10
1        A     2    15
2        A     3    10
3        A     4    15
4        B     1    40
5        B     2    30
6        B     3    40
7        B     4    30
8        C     1    80
9        C     2    70
10       C     3    80
11       C     4    70
12       D     6    75
13       D     8    75
```

Comment: This way it gives out error of ```ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable``` . Maybe due to some type does not have the value accordingly?